# How to change the stroke thickness of a text?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I want to change the thickness of the text.

In css there is a property for this

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width
```

Is there an analog in PyQt5

Changing the font to a thinner one is not an option since I use a unique font that does not have bold italic versions and so on.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QRadioButton, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, 
    QApplication, QGraphicsScene,QGraphicsView, QGraphicsLinearLayout, QGraphicsWidget, QWidget, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QPoint,Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(800, 800)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText('<div>&#xe202;</div>')

        font_id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(url)
        if font_id == -1:
            print('not fond')



        font = QFont("my-font",18)



        label.setStyleSheet('''font-size: 80pt; font-family: my-font;''')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `font-weight` property, values 100-900 have varying thickness. There's an equivalent method with `QFont.setWeight()`.

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Hello World'), 0, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        for i in range(1, 10):
            lbl = QLabel(f'({i * 100}) Hello World')
            lbl.setStyleSheet(f'font-weight: {i * 100}')
            grid.addWidget(lbl, i, 0)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QLabel {
            font-size: 24pt;
            font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        }''')
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Although this will not work for all fonts. You could alternatively subclass QLabel and reimplement `paintEvent` to draw an outline of the text in the window color.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class ThinLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addText(event.rect().bottomLeft(), self.font(), self.text())
        qp.setPen(QPen(self.palette().color(QPalette.Window), 2))
        qp.setBrush(self.palette().text())
        qp.drawPath(path)


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Hello World'), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(ThinLabel('Hello World'), 1, 0)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QLabel {
            font-size: 80pt;
            font-family: Helvetica Neue;
        }''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: The second example does not work with my font.
Font cannot be converted to letter `<div>&#xe202;</div>` in `✰`

Comment: @askqest That star actually has the HTML entity `&#10032;` If you convert it to unicode hexadecimal representation `setText('\u2730')` it should work.

Comment: I know that the asterisk is unicode. I just took it for clarity. I need that <div>&#xe202;</div> to transform into a symbol from my-font.